# H10 error when trying to start heroku app

Tags: python, flask, heroku

I am trying to start my heroku app with a python flask app, but I am getting the h10 error and the only thing I can see in the log is the Tkinter not found but I am not using Tkinter in this project please help. I've been searching on the web and on other stack overflow questions, but most just say to make sure you don't declare a port or some js server thing. I haven't found anything that helps and when I read the log all I see is the Tkinter but I tried to purge it from my code but it still tries to call it.

```
2022-03-16T08:23:39.914386+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-03-16T08:23:43.407711+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn app:app`
2022-03-16T08:23:44.518553+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-16 08:23:44 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2022-03-16T08:23:44.518954+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-16 08:23:44 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:46256 (4)
2022-03-16T08:23:44.518997+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-16 08:23:44 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2022-03-16T08:23:44.522063+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-16 08:23:44 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2022-03-16T08:23:44.585943+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-16 08:23:44 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2022-03-16T08:23:44.594660+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-03-16T08:23:44.617799+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-16 08:23:44 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2022-03-16T08:23:44.617801+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-03-16T08:23:44.617801+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
2022-03-16T08:23:44.617802+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2022-03-16T08:23:44.617802+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2022-03-16T08:23:44.617803+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2022-03-16T08:23:44.617803+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2022-03-16T08:23:44.617804+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2022-03-16T08:23:44.617804+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2022-03-16T08:23:44.617804+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2022-03-16T08:23:44.617805+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2022-03-16T08:23:44.617805+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2022-03-16T08:23:44.617805+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2022-03-16T08:23:44.617806+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2022-03-16T08:23:44.617806+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
2022-03-16T08:23:44.617807+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2022-03-16T08:23:44.617807+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2022-03-16T08:23:44.617808+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2022-03-16T08:23:44.617809+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
2022-03-16T08:23:44.617809+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2022-03-16T08:23:44.617809+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2022-03-16T08:23:44.617810+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
2022-03-16T08:23:44.617810+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
2022-03-16T08:23:44.617810+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
2022-03-16T08:23:44.617811+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 4, in <module>
2022-03-16T08:23:44.617811+00:00 app[web.1]: from turtle import back
2022-03-16T08:23:44.617811+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/turtle.py", line 107, in <module>
2022-03-16T08:23:44.617811+00:00 app[web.1]: import tkinter as TK
2022-03-16T08:23:44.617812+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>    
2022-03-16T08:23:44.617812+00:00 app[web.1]: import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
2022-03-16T08:23:44.617812+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
2022-03-16T08:23:44.617924+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-16 08:23:44 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2022-03-16T08:23:44.626229+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-16 08:23:44 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2022-03-16T08:23:44.626231+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-03-16T08:23:44.626232+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
2022-03-16T08:23:44.626232+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2022-03-16T08:23:44.626233+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2022-03-16T08:23:44.626233+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2022-03-16T08:23:44.626233+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2022-03-16T08:23:44.626234+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2022-03-16T08:23:44.626234+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2022-03-16T08:23:44.626234+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2022-03-16T08:23:44.626235+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2022-03-16T08:23:44.626235+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2022-03-16T08:23:44.626235+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2022-03-16T08:23:44.626236+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2022-03-16T08:23:44.626236+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
2022-03-16T08:23:44.626236+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2022-03-16T08:23:44.626237+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2022-03-16T08:23:44.626237+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2022-03-16T08:23:44.626238+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
2022-03-16T08:23:44.626238+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2022-03-16T08:23:44.626238+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2022-03-16T08:23:44.626239+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
2022-03-16T08:23:44.626239+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
2022-03-16T08:23:44.626239+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
2022-03-16T08:23:44.626240+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 4, in <module>
2022-03-16T08:23:44.626240+00:00 app[web.1]: from turtle import back
2022-03-16T08:23:44.626240+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/turtle.py", line 107, in <module>
2022-03-16T08:23:44.626241+00:00 app[web.1]: import tkinter as TK
2022-03-16T08:23:44.626241+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>    
2022-03-16T08:23:44.626242+00:00 app[web.1]: import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
2022-03-16T08:23:44.626242+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
2022-03-16T08:23:44.626370+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-16 08:23:44 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2022-03-16T08:23:44.660683+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-16 08:23:44 +0000] [4] [WARNING] Worker with pid 10 was terminated due to signal 15
2022-03-16T08:23:44.759567+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-16 08:23:44 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2022-03-16T08:23:44.759605+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-16 08:23:44 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2022-03-16T08:23:44.900215+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2022-03-16T08:23:44.961553+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2022-03-16T08:23:46.285089+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=uab3v3tournament.herokuapp.com request_id=fbc0a20c-6c92-4455-b730-0d57397cde41 fwd="50.86.240.117" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-03-16T08:23:46.960838+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=uab3v3tournament.herokuapp.com request_id=15532e96-e63b-44d5-8f2a-8ec26cffee08 fwd="50.86.240.117" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-03-16T08:23:47.166898+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=uab3v3tournament.herokuapp.com request_id=0b46786b-0c9b-43fd-ba78-07110a6f0b31 fwd="50.86.240.117" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
 protocol=https
```

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

```
click==8.0.4
colorama==0.4.4
Flask==2.0.3
Flask-Admin==1.6.0
Flask-Login==0.5.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1
Flask-WTF==1.0.0
greenlet==1.1.2
gunicorn==20.1.0
itsdangerous==2.1.0
Jinja2==3.0.3
MarkupSafe==2.1.0
SQLAlchemy==1.4.32
Werkzeug==2.0.3
WTForms==3.0.1
```

```
from distutils.command.sdist import sdist
from enum import unique
from genericpath import exists
from turtle import back
from flask_admin import Admin, AdminIndexView
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView
from wtforms import Form, BooleanField, StringField, PasswordField, validators
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template, session, url_for, request, flash
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey, select
from datetime import datetime
import sqlite3
import os
from flask import g, send_from_directory
from flask_login import login_required, login_user, current_user, login_manager, logout_user, UserMixin, LoginManager




app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']= 'sqlite:///test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'sdafwer3rw93ur9wu0er339de'

admin = Admin(app, url = '/sakjhfajsewdsjasfe')
#sakjhfajsewdsjasfe

      
class Forms(db.Model):  
    __tablename__ = 'forms'  
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)  
    names = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable = False)
    emails = db.Column(db.String(200), unique = False)
    team_name_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('team_names.id'))
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Forms %r>' % self.id
    
    def __init__(self, names, emails, team_names):
        self.names = names
        self.emails = emails
        self.team_names = team_names


                
class Team_names(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'team_names'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    team_name = db.Column(db.String(200), unique = True)
    formss = db.relationship('Forms', backref = 'team_names', lazy=True)  
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Team_names %r>' % self.id

    def __init__(self, team_name):
        self.team_name = team_name  


admin.add_view(ModelView(Forms, db.session))
admin.add_view(ModelView(Team_names, db.session))




  

@app.route('/favicon.ico')
def favicon():
    return send_from_directory(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static'), 'favicon.ico', mimetype='image/icon.png')

    
@app.route('/starthere', methods=['POST','GET'])
def first():
    return render_template('first.html')

@app.route('/new', methods=['POST','GET'])
def new():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        givenname = request.form['names']
        givenemail = request.form['emails']
        giventeamnames = request.form['team_names']
        
        adding1 = Team_names(team_name = giventeamnames)
        adding = Forms(names = givenname, emails = givenemail, team_names=adding1) 
        
        
        try: 
            
            db.session.add(adding)
            db.session.add(adding1)
            db.session.commit()
            return render_template('thankyou.html')
        except: 
            return render_template('fail1.html')
    else:
        return render_template('new.html')

@app.route('/join', methods=['POST','GET'])   
def join():
   
    teams = Team_names.query.with_entities(Team_names.team_name)
    for team in teams:
       team = Team_names.team_name
       
    

    if request.method == 'POST':
    
        givennames = request.form['names']   
        givenemails = request.form['emails']
        select = request.form.get("selected")   
        selected_team = db.session.query(Team_names).filter(Team_names.team_name == select).first()
        adding = Forms(names = givennames, emails = givenemails, team_names = selected_team)        
        
        try: 
            
            db.session.add(adding)    
            db.session.commit()
            return render_template('thankyou.html')   
        except:
            return render_template('fail2.html')
             
    else:
        return render_template("join.html", teams=teams)  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate problem is caused by the following import:

```py
from turtle import back
```

It doesn't make much sense to use [the `turtle` module](https://docs.python.org/library/turtle.html) in a web application. Fortunately, you don't seem to actually be using it.

Remove that line, commit, and redeploy.

---

Once that's done, you will probably find that your SQLite database [doesn't behave as you expect it to](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bheroku%5D+sqlite+reset).

Heroku's [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) makes file-based databases like SQLite a poor choice. A client-server database like PostgreSQL will work much better. Heroku's own [Postgres service](https://www.heroku.com/postgres) might be a good place to start.